# socket.error: [Errno 19] No such device error

Tags: python, python-2.7

when i run this script for detecting cam table exhaustion detection script , the following error occur.

```
  File "camtable.py", line 22, in <module>
    sniff(iface=interface,prn=monitorPackets)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 561, in sniff
    s = L2socket(type=ETH_P_ALL, *arg, **karg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 455, in __init__
    self.ins.bind((iface, type))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 19] No such device
```

would require some guidance.

```
import sys
import scapy
import datetime
from scapy.all import *
THRESH=(254/4)
START = 5

def monitorPackets(p):
    if p.haslayer(IP):
        hwSrc = p.getlayer(Ether).src
        if hwSrc not in hwList:
            hwList.append(hwSrc)
        delta = datetime.datetime.now() - start
        if((delta.seconds > START) and ((len(hwList)/delta.seconds) > THRESH)):
            print "[*]- Detected CAM Table Attack."


interface = sys.argv[0]
hwList = []
start = datetime.datetime.now()

sniff(iface=interface,prn=monitorPackets)
```

Comment: Here's a hint: `print sys.argv`

Comment: If all of this is copy/pasted code you are not even planning to understand, please say so.

Comment: "when I run this script"... How do you run it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `sys.argv[1]` there. What value are you attempting to pass in?

Comment: when put sys.argv[1] . i get the index out of range error instead.Should i put a try and catch ?

Comment: @ku1918 If you put `sys.argv[1]`, you'll, of course, have to provide a command line argument. On a call `myscript foo bar`, `argv[0]` will contain `'myscript'`, `argv[1]` will be `'foo'` and `argv[2]` `'bar'`.

Comment: Again, what do you expect the `iface` parameter to contain, and how are you passing it in?

Comment: @ku1918 How to do what?